# IndexTank tutorial for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, indextank

I am building a simple Rails website, where users can create posts and people can search for posts. I am hosting this application with heroku.

I was looking for options for the search functionality, and found IndexTank (starter) as the only free option with heroku.

Is it a good idea to use IndexTank for a requirement like mine? Should I go ahead with using just ActiveRecord finders to implement this search or I should use IndexTank?

Additionally, can anyone provide me with a very nice IndexTank tutorial to get started with? I found few tutorials, but could not really progress with those. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if you have seen the official IndexTank gem for Rails:

https://github.com/kidpollo/tanker

The README file comes with some examples.

Also, here's a complete demo app:

https://github.com/adrnai/rails-3-tanker-demo

Please let me know if this helps, you can always email support @ indextank dot com and we'll help you get started!

Comment: While trying to use Tanker, my progress was stopped after I created the tanker.rb with value **YourAppName::Application.config.index_tank_url = 'http://:xxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.api.indextank.com'**. I have no idea what value to set for index_tank_url. And I have been getting the error **bad URI(is not URI?):**. Please help.

Comment: I get **Unknown pagination backend** for Tanker. I am using Rails 3. What do I do?

Comment: You need to install will_paginate or kaminari gem.